# widget.xml overwriting from theme

Tags: magento2

Can it be possible to overwrite the widget.xml data of the module in some convenient way (instead of editing module source)? For example if there is need to add more containers  to place widget or to add another template to it.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot resolve this problem with composer. Create simple module with widget.xml file and add it as requirements for you theme.